# Page Events fail to trigger after loading GridView with larger data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a page with GridView control in my ASP.Net web application. The page events like Page_Load, and button related events like Click and also the Grid related events like PageIndex changed event are triggering as expected when the GridView is loaded with fewer data like less than or equal to 1000 rows, but when the GridView is loaded with large data like more than 25000+ records, all the above-said events are failing to trigger and page become un-responsive. Hopefully, the time taken to fetch 25000+ records is what makes the events fail. Please help me in this regard, it really become a tricky problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one on planet earth is going to load up a dataset with 25,000 records, and THEN try and page that. I mean if you display say even 50 per page (already WAY too many rows? Do you really want to abuse and hate and torture your users that much?).

At even 50 rows per page? That is going to result in 500 pages! If a user could page say 1 page every 2 seconds, then you talking about MORE then 15 minutes of time to page though that, and it just does not make sense. You need to provide some kind of filter here. By city, by region, by type, or whatever.

I mean, think of a bank machine. Does it FIRST download every single account, and THEN ask you for what account to work on? Of course not!

Would you do a internet search, download the WHOLE internet and then force the user to say use ctrl-f? Of course not!!!

There is simple no practical use case to attempt to load that many rows of data.

I mean, out of those 25,000 rows, what row does the user want to see? And if just 10 people hit the web site, you pulled 250,000 rows, and NOT done ANY useful work so far, and users are still faced with a mountain of records.

There is simply no possible way a user can process that much information, and worse forcing them to page though 100's of rows makes ZERO sense. You have to re-think this approach - perhaps re-think your approach to most things in life?

You would have to make a REMARKABLE case and narrative as to why you want, need and would do this in the first place?

Can you google and find a solution to your issue? Nope! So you mean with 20+ years of posts, blogs, questions, and no one on planet earth has a solution for you?

Answer: no they don't have a solution because no one works this way!!!

So, you need to prompt, or provide some kind of searching/filtering system here.

However, there might be some case in which you at least want to "hint" or "show" to the user that a VERY large number of records exists as a result of their search.

And also keep in mind, that SQL server does have paging options. In effect, you would (should) then consider using server side paging here.

The datapager for a gridview/listview etc. is really only a "convenience" option. But, since say 200, or even 1000 rows can be pulled quite fast, then the data pager THEN lets you break those 1000 rows into say 10 or 20 chunks of say 20 rows.

However, while I can't think of a scenario in which so many records would require paging? You can adopt as noted sql paging.

it works like this:

```
DECLARE @PageNumber AS INT
DECLARE @RowsOfPage AS INT
SET @PageNumber=2
SET @RowsOfPage=4
SELECT FruitName,Price FROM SampleFruits
ORDER BY Price 
OFFSET (@PageNumber-1)*@RowsOfPage ROWS
FETCH NEXT @RowsOfPage ROWS ONLY
```

In other words the above will ONLY return a dataset of 4, or say we could change to 20 rows. That means that you ONLY ever pull from the server 20 rows at a time, and THEN only ever shove 20 rows into the grid.

So, to get around your problem, then I would dump the built in pager, and roll your own pager based on the above concept. That way, your grid or whatever, will run fast, and instant, if you have 500, or 10 million rows.

So, as a tip?

I would not load more then say 300, maybe 600 rows and then let the built in datapagers go to work. Beyond that data set size? You have to spend more time on providing some type of UI filter, or simple drop the built in pager, and roll your own. Based on the above T-SQL, you can see that building a stored procedure, and then persisting a page number, and dropping in your own next/previous button would be quite easy. And on your page load, you could do a count(*) against the table based on your criteria. After all, maybe your ARE ALREADY providing some search criteria, and maybe your data table is say 10 or 20 million rows. And these days, 10 or 20 million rows in a database table is NOT all that large.

so, you could display a total results count (say 50,000 rows). But, if you page say 20 or 30 row at a time, you would in fact only ever be pulling 20-30 rows at a time from the server and that is "nothing" for asp.net.

At the end of the day, don't attempt to pull 25,000 records into some dataset, and THEN attempt to page that large dataset - it not going to work well, and is not at all practical from both a user (UI) point of view, nor from a developer point of view.

So, I would not suggest using a data pager for more then say 400-500 rows absolute tops. After that, you need to roll your own, and user sql server paging, not the built in data pagers - they simply are not and never were built for paging large datasets.

You can load up say max 200, maybe 300 rows and THEN page that data set to the user. After that number of rows, you need to spend some time and care and cook up a different approach.

Comment: Hi @Albert D. Kallal, thank you for your suggestion and response. Am already using some filters to get the data, but the thing is, here am getting the data from multiple tables (16 tables), when the user selects "All" option from the filter dropdown. Only in this case, the dataset is getting overloaded with 25K records. And am using Postgre SQL as my backend. For sure I'll apply some other more technics to filter out the data. Thank you.

Comment: You have to introduce some kind of sql server site paging here. The example t-sql I posted was for sql server, but without a doubt, PostGres has this feature also. So, as noted, you could take the filter, and do a "count(*) of some sort to show the number of records, but you NOT pull that many records. The same goes for say a combo box. They are good for about 50 choices. After that, you have to adopt a different UI (or risk bad UI, and that of beating your users over the head with a baseball bat - and that's just mean and torturing them).  This does suggest you have to roll your own pager.